# SegFault when dereferencing integer from void ptr

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, dereference

This is my code, Tuple.c, it produces a SegFault at the line with a comment saying so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dbwait();

typedef struct STuple {
    int tSize;
    void** values;
} Tuple;

Tuple* CreateTuple(int n_args, ...) {
    va_list varlist;
    va_start(varlist, n_args);

    int varsSize;
    void** vars = (void**)malloc(n_args * sizeof(void*));

    for (int i = 0; i < n_args; i++) {
        void* arg = va_arg(varlist, void*);
        varsSize += sizeof(arg);
        vars[i] = arg;
        printf("Arg ptr = %p\n", arg);
    }

    // Size of all of the arguments + size of an int value (varsSize) since Tuple has an array of void* and a single int.
    Tuple* t = (Tuple*)malloc(varsSize + sizeof(varsSize));

    t->values = vars;
    t->tSize = n_args;

    va_end(varlist);

    return t;
}

void FreeTuple(Tuple* t) {
    printf("Freeing tuple at %p\n", (void*)t);
    free(t->values);
    free(t);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Tuple* rt = CreateTuple(3, 625, 173, 50);

    int length = rt->tSize;

    printf("%i\n", length); // Prints 3, as defined in the call to CreateTuple
    dbwait();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        printf("index = %i: ", i);
        dbwait();

        void* ptr = rt->values[i];
        printf("At ptr %p, ", ptr); dbwait();

        int value = *((int*)ptr); // SegFault Occurs here!
        printf("with value = %d\n", value);
        dbwait();
    }

    dbwait();

    FreeTuple(rt);

    return 0;
}

void dbwait() {
    char* stop = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    scanf("%c", stop);
    free(stop);
}
```

I know for a fact that the address assigned to `ptr` at `ptr = rt->values[i];` is correct since whenever I copy that address as its printed from gdb and do print (address), it prints out the correct value of 625.

Why am I getting a SegFault when the address correctly points to an integer?

**EDIT:** I've replaced the current code content of my question with my entire tuple.c file, shown above, as requested by other users.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. And what do you think is the result of calling `malloc` and then immediately overwriting what it returns on the next line? That's not the correct way to use `malloc` and if you think it is then would suggest you dig out your fav C text book again.

Comment: Would you mind providing code for CreateTuple as well? I think the problem is in it, because `malloc`s and variables in your example are excessive and do absolutely nothing, so the whole example can be shortened to `*((int*)CreateTuple(3, 625, 173, 50)->values[i])`.

Comment: You say "I know that all these mallocs are excessive".  In fact they are obscuring your example.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you haven't provided a clear and simple example that demonstrates the problem.  Reduce your code to the smallest possible segment that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I did that to the best of my abilities. Like I said, I'm very new to C so I don't fully understand how to refactor my code to the smallest possible segment. Someone else wanted more of my code, and others want less. So, heres all my code in my Tuple.c file, and I'm using your input in your answer to get towards a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `*ptr` is 625, then `*valPtr` is dereferencing the address 625.

If you are running this inside the debugger, take a look at the value of valPtr at the time you are dereferencing it.

Comment: I've edited my question with the actual code I'm debugging.

Comment: You may actually be leading me in the right direction. Looks like 0x271 is actually 625 in the decimal, so clearly I need to be creating an int*, malloc that and assign the value in the va_list to that.

Thank you for actually giving me some good input.

Comment: lead me in the right direction. My code for Tuple was actually working perfectly, but when calling CreateTuple, I should be passing pointers to values instead of values. I'm passing pointers through CreateTuple and it works now! Huge thanks to jdigital.

Answer (score 0):

All of your mallocs are leaking memory because you over write mallocs return on the next line:

```
void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(rt->values[i]));
ptr = rt->values[i]; // You've now lost the pointer to malloced memory.
```

It looks like you want something like `*ptr = ...` to put something into your newly created block. In the case of `intPtr`, you set it's value to an int, and then try to use that as a pointer again. Since it is not likely to be a valid address you get a segfault.

Comment: I had a note saying that my mallocs were excessive and I knew they were leaking memory. Please read questions in their entirety before posting answers. I've edited my question with the entire actual code file that causes the segfault.

**Edit:** It looks like @jdigital might be leading me in the right direction. Update soon.